# Prevent default drag in input type range in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to prevent the default drag feature of input range, with out impacting the click functionality? The user needs to change the values using clicking but not using drag.

```
<input   
  type="range"
  min="0"
  max="100"
  step="1"
  class="custom-audio-slider"
/>
```

demo : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GVF5ZH6S3HSF

Comment: I hope this help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

Comment: No adding draggable:false is not helpful. added code snippet in above @drsaud

Comment: You're combatting what the element is meant to do - such endeavours often end up in confusion. Either look at a regular input field, radio buttons or a dropdown if the click is that imporant. Sidenote: Try using code sharing sites like jsfiddle or codepen.io.

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      value: 7,
      drag: false,
      move: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dragging() {
      this.drag = true
    },
    stopDragging() {
      this.drag = false
      this.move = false
    },
    moving() {
      if(this.drag) {
        this.move = true
      }
    },
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <span id="valBox"></span>
  <div @mouseover="stopDragging">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" v-model="value" :disabled ="move"
     @mousemove="moving" @mousedown="dragging" @mouseup="stopDragging">
     <p>{{ value }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```